# Alternative for toString() in java

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xjc

What I have is an unmarshalled java object from XML. The parts of this unmarshalled object is sent to various class for processing. I need to log the contents of the unmarshalled object. I can easily override the `toString()` method  but the problem is that in this case the classes are generated at build time using xjc and I cannot override the toString() in those classes as they will be removed when generated again.

I am looking for some other alternative to print the contents. Any Idea ?

Comment: If you can easily override toString() then why doesn't you? Are you looking for a difficult/complex solution?

Comment: What doesn't `toString()` do that you want to be done?

Comment: The problem is that in this case the classes are generated at build time using xjc and I cannot override the toString() in those classes as they will be removed when generated again.

Comment: @TejasArjun if the classes are being re-generated how does the new method you add going to be merged back?

Comment: @Pangea That is the problem I am facing. If I override the toString(), how do I merge back ? By th way, one of the reader, bmargulies
, in below thread, has suggested to use xjc plugin. I am looking at the details now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an xjc plugin to generate the toString you want.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `toString()` for marshalling.  That's not what it is intended for.  (Refer to the javadocs for `java.lang.Object` for a guide to what that method *is* intended for.)

Even if you do decide to implement marshalling / unmarshalling by hand, you should not attempt to use `toString()` for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a utility class that uses reflection to inspect the object and either return a string representation of it (in whatever format you need) or have it log the string representation directly.

Comment: I gave a thought at that solution. Maybe I could use some library like xstream to log in xml format..Was just looking for any other solution.

Answer (score 0):

Write a helper class which takes the unmarshalled Java Object and gives you its string representation using reflection, if you don want to use reflection since you know your xsd and unmarshalled contents you can hard code them.